# how do i correctly proxy https requests to another https server for cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ssl, https, proxy

I have a number of different servers running on my system, all of them running a secure connection on there own port, etc. 50001,50002,50003...
all of thees can be accessed directly from https://domain1.com:50001 ...
now, not only do I want to limit the number of ports, but also change the domain so etc.

```
https://domain1.com:50001 <- https://srv1.domain2.com:443  
https://domain1.com:50002 <- https://srv2.domain2.com:443  
https://domain1.com:50003 <- https://srv3.domain2.com:443
```

All of thees servers run separate nodejs instances.

Now I want to build a proxy than redirect this, and I have chosen nodejs since everything else we do is in nodejs.

what i have now:

```
var app = require('express')();
var options = {
    key  : fs.readFileSync(CONFIG.sslKey).toString(),
    cert : fs.readFileSync(CONFIG.sslCertificate).toString(),
    ca   : fs.readFileSync(CONFIG.sslCA).toString()
};
var http = require('https').Server(options,app);
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    ssl: {
             key  : fs.readFileSync(CONFIGsecure.sslKey).toString(),
             cert : fs.readFileSync(CONFIGsecure.sslCertificate).toString(),
             ca   : fs.readFileSync(CONFIGsecure.sslCA).toString()
         },
    secure: true
});

var handleRequests = function(req, res){
    proxyTo = "https://domain1.com:50001"; <= some logic chooses this based on req.headers.host
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: proxyTo });
};

app.get('/*', handleRequests );
app.post('/*', handleRequests );
app.put('/*', handleRequests );
app.delete('/*', handleRequests );

http.listen(443, function(){});
```

okay so this actually works very well, everything is going where it should go in a browser, and in a cordova app using jquery ajax everything also works very well.
however if i use

```
FileTransfer().download(...)
```

I get error code 3 (connection error).
If I connect directly to https://domain1.com:50001 (direct) the app works, but if i connect to https://srv1.domain2.com:443 (the proxy) the app does not work.

All the certificates are valid, wildcard certificate on *.domain2.com and single certificate on domain1.com.
The end servers has domain1.com certificate installed and the proxy has *.domain2.com wildcard certificate installed.

Any idea on how to correctly setup a proxy server? The system is windows server 2012 R2 and I am open to use a real proxy if needed. However it would be nice with a solution as simple as possible.

I have tried example two form here:
http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-intro/
however this is the same problem, and it is only GET requests.

I have also tried disabling https on the end server so thats it's only the proxy that is secure, however, same result...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found the issue, for some reason req.headers.host string also contained the :port, and i was only switching on the address. now everything works perfekt.